# jQuery to detect page resizing or tablets & mobile devices

Tags: jquery

I'm creating one break point on my site so it is responsive for tablets and mobile devices.  All is going well except I want to move a piece of content from the bottom and append it under the navigation.

I have a simple two column layout right-column and left-column. The piece(s) of HTML are located in the right column.  I need to detect when the screensize is at or below 558px and then move things around.

HTML:

```
<div class="main wrapper">
    <div class="content-left"></div>
    <div class="content-right">
        // three divs containing awesome content
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
 <script>
    var windowsize = $(window).width();

   if (windowsize < 559) {
   //if the window is less than 559px wide then prepend the following
   console.log('Window resized!!!');
   $(".now-playing-title, h1.now-playing-title, .live-now-block, .now-playing").prependTo('.content-left'); 
}

</script>
```

Working soluntion: I used .insertBefore() instead of .preprend() (which moved everything inside the column-left div) and wrapped it all with document.ready() so it would fire after the page was fully loaded.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var windowsize = $(window).width();

    if (windowsize < 559) {
    //if the window is less than 559px wide then append NowPlaying
    console.log('Window resized!!!');
    $(".now-playing-title, h1.now-playing-title, .live-now-block, .now-playing").insertBefore('.content-left'); 
    }    
    });
</script>
```

Comment: create the content in the space you need it to be and hide/show it based on browser width using css media query

Comment: I'm confused, are you just trying to trigger jQuery when you reach a certain size or are you just making the ui responsive?

Comment: Trying to trigger jQuery when a certain page size is reached.  It's not the best solution because the user needs to reload the page when resized.

Comment: @Huangism why should I have to create duplicate content?

Comment: @user2501654 because you said you need it at different places. Also this allows you to control when to show/hide using css instead of js

Answer (score 1):

This should not be done in javascript.

You can use css media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 558px) {
  ... do your thing
}
```

Have a read of [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design).

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain clearly, and for that I appologize.  I'm just trying to move HTML around.  All the CSS is good.  Just having trouble with the jquery.  Thnaks

Comment: You should not be moving HTML around based on your screen size. This is what media queries does.

Comment: @robadams read his question, how would you append content with a media query?

Comment: Sorry, I'm relocating a piece of HTML.  For example, when column-right is below column-left I need a piece of content moved to the top.  It's a site that plays music so on mobile I need the now-playing song at the top for useability.  Anyway I figured it out.  added document.ready().  Thanks tho.

Answer (score -2):

http://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   if ($('.content-left').is(':empty') && $(window).width()  <= 559){

   console.log('Window resized!!!');
   $(".now-playing-title, h1.now-playing-title, .live-now-block, .now-playing").prependTo('.content-left');
   }
});
```

Comment: This will call a prepend at every resize event.